# Emulator Erro - dont run

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Hello I am not getting to start my emulator appears this message and I can not do anything else when I run flutter doctor I do not see any errors.
Someone can help me!

Event log
11:21   Emulator: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

11:21   Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

[image]

Comment: Erase (wipe data) and restart the emulator

Comment: I’ve already deleted it and created it again and it’s still the same!